# Is there a way to capture an invalid named page handler method call?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I define a couple of named handler methods in one Razor Page for using them from Ajax calls. It works OK for well formed requests, but how can I trap requests to this page that specify non-existent named handler methods?

In this page (**EDIT**:the page where I want to capture invalid calls) all named handler methods have same signature, similar to this:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> OnGet__name_for_the_method__Async(string uid) {...}
```

When this happends the `OnGetAsync()` method is not called. (**EDIT**: No handler method is called at all, only the constructor, and the page is rendered incomplete, with errors, exceptions, etc)

In other razor page (**EDIT**: I checked to see if same thing occurred in another page, so I placed breakpoints in all methods as before and could see that, in this case, `OnGetAsync()` was indeed called), with named handler methods that have different signatures, I used following code, that in some cases worked:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    if (this.RouteData.Values.Keys.Contains("handler"))
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    ...etc...
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `OnGetAsync` handler with ajax,here is a demo:

cshtml:

```
<button onclick="postdata()">click</button>
@section scripts{ 
<script>
    function postdata() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "",
            data: {"id":1},
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

cshtml.cs:

```
// As route doesn't contain handler=xxx,you cannot get this.RouteData.Values["handler"].
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
            {
                return Page();
            }
```

result:
[image]

**Update:**

You can change `OnGet__name_for_the_method__Async` to `OnGetName_for_the_method__Async`,I test and find when the first Letter is uppercase,the method will be called successfully.

result:

[image]

Comment: This is for normal operation, not for capturing invalid requests.

Comment: What does `capturing invalid requests` mean?OnGet__name_for_the_method__Async?

Comment: Invalid request means specifying one named handler method that does not exist in the model class, like at the beginning of my question "...requests to this page that specify non-existent named handler methods?"

Comment: You can check my updated answer,you need to change the handler name to a valid one.